# Cancel axios request when this is called again with an on change method - Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, request, cancellation

I have this component with an on change method that makes a request to the api:

```
<v-autocomplete
  class="caption"
  v-model="input.id"
  background-color="#F8F9FB"
  :items="segmentsList"
  item-value="Id"
  item-text="Name"
  return-object
  dense
  solo
  flat
  @change="getAmount(input.id, index)"
></v-autocomplete>
```

Every time the component changes the information, the request is made.
I need to cancel the previous request if the response is still in process.

This is the code of the request, but its status doesn't change to canceled, it stays in pending and returns the previous response when finished. I only need it to return the response of the last request made.

```
getAmount(item, index) {
   this.loading = true;

   if(this.axiosCall){
     this.axiosCall.cancel();
   }
   const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
   this.axiosCall = CancelToken.source();

   ApiService.get("campaign/getSegmentSize/" + this.dbSelected + "/" + item.Id, 
    { cancelToken:  this.axiosCall.token }
   )
   .then((response) => {
     this.loading = false;
     this.segments[this.dbSelected].segment[index].amount = response.data.subscribers;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
       console.log('API request is canceled...', error.message);
     } else {
       if (typeof error.response.data === "object") {
         Object.values(error.response.data)
           .flat()
           .forEach((error) => {
             this.loading = false;
             this.$store.dispatch("setSnackbar", {
               color: "tvf_secondary",
               text: error.message,
               timeout: 3000,
             });
           });
         }
      }
    }); 
  },
```

Comment: And how would you know that this is the last request? The user can change input as many times as he wants and so requests will be fired. Besides, every request's response will override the previous request's response so there will always be the latest response. Can you elaborate on the use case more?